How to use charcoal ash for
I have a lot of charcoal ash after doing BBQ and it is hard to throw it but I read somewhere, it can be good for grass, I have got patchy garden and my goal is to make it beautiful and lush.
Will spreading/throwing ash in garden will help fertilize the grass?

]2
]3

Depends on what type of charcoal - if it was treated (usually sold as 'easy to light') that should not be used in the garden.

@Bamboo: OTOH is is used, so the easy to light part should already by burned (it is the purpose: burn at very beginning to ignite the rest). And I would be surprised it treated material which we uses for food preparation is worse for garden then for us. -- To ::1, which quantities are we talking about?

@Bamboo I use Baq b king lumpwood coal

Closely related though I personally disagree with most of the answers there. Answer-in-comments: if the bag claims it's wood char it might be nice on a compost pile. Longer statement here.

As a general answer charcoal ash from barbeques is not good to add to your garden.  The problems with charcoal ash are:

can contain residue or byproducts from lighter fluid
charcoal briquettes commonly contain binders which remain after burning

What does wood ash do?

increases the alkalinity of the soil
contains potassium and calcium with smaller amounts of phosphorous and magnesium
should only be applied after determining the pH of your soil and to plants which it will benefit

Different species of grass have different preferences for soil pH so in order to decide if applying wood ash is appropriate you should get a soil test done and find out what kind of grass species is in your lawn.

What about adding to compost and letting nature decide?

@YosefBaskin from here http://www.charcoalbriquettepress.com/blog/The-Kind-of-Binder-for-Coal-Briquetting.html "The cheapest and most widely used binder is traded as asphalt - the heavy residuum from petroleum"  Composting is not going to change that into good soil.  Other types of charcoal briquettes can use less toxic binders such as starch.

@kevinskio: I do not think it is allowed in Europe (both sides of channel) (and I assume OP is in Europe, by vegetation, building and furniture). And from description of product and googling we get 100% natural lumpwood charcoal, * with no additives*.

@GiacomoCatenazzi  Sure, with that phrase it sounds good.  I am familiar with products such as pesticides and fertilizers that don't list the inactive ingredients.  Product labelling is out my scope to comment on.  Why not add your own answer?

@kevinskio: I'm not answering because I lack of sufficient information: quantities (and the type of ash: just ash or also including pieces of coal: we see both being put on gardens). Your answer is on safe side, so without further information I would not write something may be misinterpreted.

So take away is that ash isn't good for the garden as it might contain binders and other byproducts also if it only applicable to apply ash if you we know the pH of the soil? If I am correct what should be the pH of the soil be to apply?

@localhost just to throw around an approximation, neutral pH is 7 and most grasses like a pH of between 5.5 and 7.  So, if your soil pH is really acidic such as less than 6 it might benefit from small applications of ash
